# `UncaughtThrowError` raised when `throw` is called in a Fiber

Tags: ruby, fibers

I ran into an `UnknownThrowError` when a `throw` is called in the context of a Fiber. I am running Ruby 2.4.1. The problem can be reproduced with the sample code as follows:

```
catch(:tag) do
  Fiber.new do
    throw(:tag)
  end.resume
end
```

Is this behavior expected? I could not find the documentation on Fibers on this. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect the other thread knows anything about it’s parent context?

Comment: I didn't know that a `catch` context is not shared with a child Fiber or Thread. I was thinking if there is any clearer documentation on this.

Comment: This is as obvious as I believe authors of `Fiber` just could not imagine anybody having a doubt here. `Fiber.new` is an _asycnhronous_ operation, that immediately returns the control. What do you think should happen in the caller when the callee in another thread throws? It might be even not alive already.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. I have overlooked the fact that `Fiber.new` should be seen as an asynchronous operation as in my actual code, all the synchronization between the root Fiber and the child Fiber were done in the context of the `catch` block. Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close because this stems from a general misunderstanding of asynchronous programming models. Too broad for a specific answer.

Comment: @Max it’s makes no sense to say it’s too broad given it’s a specific yes/no question asked with code example.  and there is no certified level of expertise in concurrent systems required to ask such a question.  it’s even possible at one point in your life you didn’t know the answer.  voting to leave open.